# Can an app build on windows server 2019 run on windows server 2016

Tags: visual-studio-2019, backwards-compatibility, windows-server-2016, windows-server-2019

I have an app that was built on windows server 2019, using Visual Studio 2019.  It fails to run on windows server 2016.

Is there a way to get this app to run on windows server 2016?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app in question was not bundling all of the MSVC redistributable files.  [CMake InstallRequiredSystemLibraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/InstallRequiredSystemLibraries.html) is used for bundling native libraries with the app, but the default behavior of that cmake function does not include the universal CRT libraries.  I simply had to add `set(CMAKE_INSTALL_UCRT_LIBRARIES true)` before `include(InstallRequiredSystemLibraries)` in the cmake configuration file (CMakeLists.txt).

An alternative solution is to manually install the latest MSVC redistributable package on the 2016 server.